# How to use if else with protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, if-statement, jasmine, protractor

I have very strange scenarios and I am not sure how to handle it.

Im a new into testning and I got a site to test where we check a cart function if its working property.

My problem is that we add x numbers of product and we do a stock check. If there is a stock conflict then we need to solve it before continue else we just continue.

I managed to create a function that looks like:

```
describe("Details page", function () {

    detailsPage = new DetailsPage();

    // The details page is accessible by the specified URL
    it(`Is defined by the URL: ${userData["url"]}${browser.baseUrl}`,
        async function () {
            await detailsPage.navigateDesktop();
        });

    // Details page has a form and it can be filled out with user data
    it("Has a form that can receive user data",
        async function() {
            await detailsPage.fillFormWithUserData();
            await utils.click(detailsPage.getForm().buttons.nextStep);
        });

    if (detailsPage.hasStockConflict()) {

        // Details page allows the user to fix conflicts in stocks
        it('Enables resolution of stock conflicts', async function () {
            // Wait for stock to fully load
            await detailsPage.hasStockConflict();
            await detailsPage.clickAllRemoveButtons();
            await detailsPage.clickAllDecreaseButtons();
        });

        // Details page allows the user to proceed to the next stage when all conflicts (if any) has been resolved
        it('Allows the user to proceed to the next stage of purchasing', async function () {
            const nextStepButton = detailsPage.getForm().buttons.nextStep;
            await utils.elementToBeClickable(nextStepButton);
            await utils.click(nextStepButton);
        });
    }
});
```

however my function problem is that I need to wait until I get a response back from the server, either I do get a stock conflict which will be triggered by:

```
hasStockConflict() //checks if there is stockConflict message in DOM
```

or I will will get redirect to new page.

My question is, how can I either make a sort functionally that checks if there is a stock conflict then we solve the if statement else we just continue without needing to do anything (Which will take me to next page)?

I have set a timeout for 1 minute. After 1 minute it will pass the test as failed.

Basically I want to solve the if statement if there is a stock conflict else we just skip it basically. I might have done misunderstood the purpose of testning so all sort of knowledge would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each test should test on specific thing. They should not contain `if...else` branching. Instead, you should have a test for each scenario. Each test should require initialized data that satisfies that specific scenario.

You have two different ways to approach this:

1. Set up data in resource that you query and request the specific data for the scenario being tested.
2. Mock the resource so that requests return mock data that is curated for the scenario being tested.

Comment: In that case it means if I want to test the stock conflict, I should in that case insert product that needs to be solved before continuing I believe right?

What would you suggest in that case if I want to make a choice that if I want to test the stock conflict or not basically? That I want to run the stock conflict function and when to not?

Comment: Did not see the edit, I added the same in my answer! Good answer!

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie I've edited my answer to include a few more details. In general, tests shouldn't decide whether to call a function or not. They should follow a specific recipe and verify that the result is correct. When there are multiple scenarios, each one should be tested separately.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Make much more sense! I agree. I didnt thought about it and I guess we all learn something new everyday. But in that case. What would you recommend me to read about to trigger if I want to run example a mock data for items that is not in stock and items in stock? If you know what I mean? :)

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie Where does the data come from in the application? If you are making a request to a REST API or some other HTTP resource, you can use a library such as `nock` or `fetch-mock` to mock the responses of the HTTP requests.

Comment: I do it by accesing the website page, add the product and then automatic the cookies will be transfared basically. But I agree. I do think I need to learn how to setup my scripts on how to test multiply tests basically. That I can run one test where I want to have only valid test through end2end and one with stock conflict etc etc... I think thats my problem right now on how to make the code so dynamic as possible and also be able to maybe tag or run the script by calling stockconflictPage.js or something like that.

Comment: Also it might be very confused when i'm writing because its pretty new for me and I believed that I did something wrong from the beginning aswell. it felts like I tried to solve the problem rather than actually test it.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Code-Apprentice has mentioned, you can set up mock data to get the response as you see fit.  You should have different responses mocked and depending on the response do one specific thing in one test. No if else stuff in the steps.
 In your case, for now, use items which you know are in stock or add dummy items which are always instock and add dummy items to your database which are out of stock. Write separate tests for both and how you see fit.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is actually true. I wrote a comment about if. So as you mentioned like having two sort of test where one of the test is to check if in stock and the other to have dummy items basically and run two different test. So I guess I would need to havefunction where I can enter maybe in params if I want to run dummy or in stock function or how would you suggest to do?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie "So as you mentioned like having two sort of test where one of the test is to check if in stock..." I think you misunderstand. The point here is that you have two tests. One that is **guaranteed** to get an item that is in stock and verifies that the following behavior act correctly for that case. The other test is **guaranteed** to get a item that is not in stock and verifies correct behavior for that case. Neither test checks whether or not the item is actually in stock. It should be built in such a way to guarantee the state that is required for that particular test.

Comment: We are talking about feature flagging the test cases which is a little different. In general we use feature flags to make sure we control what features are active. We provide `hooks` in the beginning of the tests so we control one feature flag and test accordingly in that test. I recommend just sticking with checking one thing in one test with some data what you see fit.

Comment: @LearningEveryday Excuess me for late response! But I agree with what you and Code-Apprentice said to me. I really to get a better grip and more understand how it is supposed to work aswell!

Answer (score 0):

What everyone was saying is that there are best practices that one should follow in order to avoid pitfalls in future...

However, the best practice #1 is **it always depends** on your company, your product, your needs. So if you decide you need to go this route, go for it

## Why your scenario doesn't work

Short answer, your `it` blocks are built before the browser started. At that time
your function can't run, and I assume fails or returns `undefined`

## Answer

With that said ^, you can't skip `it`, just place your logic inside like this

```
        it('Enables resolution of stock conflicts', async function () {
          if (detailsPage.hasStockConflict()) {
            // Wait for stock to fully load
            await detailsPage.hasStockConflict();
            await detailsPage.clickAllRemoveButtons();
            await detailsPage.clickAllDecreaseButtons();

            const nextStepButton = detailsPage.getForm().buttons.nextStep;
            await utils.elementToBeClickable(nextStepButton);
            await utils.click(nextStepButton);
          }
        });
```

Comment: Ohhh thank you so much! I do understand what you mean and I do think I might still have a problem about it. The problem is that the `detailsPage.hasStockConflict()` is a element. where we are waiting for the elemen to pop up and if we dont find it within 1 minute then it will throw a timeout which will cause the whole `it` function to be as FAILED test basically. I do think maybe it is actually better to have it seperated test where we test both valid stock and the stock conflict. unless you suggest something else? :D

Comment: So yet I do need to wait a couple of seconds to see if there is a stock conflict or not. and here is where my problem is. If there is no stock conflict then we will be redirected to next page, else we will get a stock conflict message and thats the reason why I do believe its better to have it as seperated tests rather than have all in one?

Comment: in this case yes, I would separate those. But in future, sooner or later you'll face the same problem where the whole test case should be conditional. Just keep in mind the solution^

Comment: Will do! However I might ask you right away. If the ```detailsPage.hasStockConflict()```, will the test case be a failed or will just the if statement be false? Because in that case it would be very handy but if I remember correctly is that when I get a timeout middle of a test case then that test case will be count as failed. If you have any suggestions about that, could you please provide me a example code because I would really appreciate it!

Comment: as an option I would just just wrap your expectation for an element in `try/catch` and in try return true and in catch return false (or the opposite). this way the it never throws an error. But there should be a better way...